# Grav CMS - image questions/problems in partial template

Tags: grav

New to Grav and am learning as I go, but have found little to no documentation on things I am trying to find out about :(

I am putting together a blog as a test and modifying the existing antimatter theme.  In /partials/blog_item.html.twig there are the following lines for images :

```
{% set header_image = page.header.header_image|defined(true) %}
{% set header_image_width  = page.header.header_image_width|defined(900) %}
{% set header_image_height = page.header.header_image_height|defined(200) %}
{% set header_image_file = page.header.header_image_file %}

{% if header_image %}
    {% if header_image_file %}
        {% set header_image_media = page.media.images[header_image_file] %}
    {% else %}
        {% set header_image_media = page.media.images|first %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ header_image_media.cropZoom(header_image_width, header_image_height).html }}
{% endif %}
```

It takes the first image used in a post and makes a 900x200 version of it as a header.  Here is what I can't figure out :

1 - How can I add a class to this image when it is output?  I want to add an img-responsive class, but see no way to do this.

2 - What if I don't want a header image at all for the post, but the post will have images in it?  Okay, so I remove the `{% set header_image_media = page.media.images|first %}` part, but with that question is how to I define what image to use as `page.media.images[header_image_file]` then if I want to use one?

3 - How can I get the full url of this header image for outputting on the page?  I am not talking about the full  tag, just the string of its full url?

Maybe these are easy, but I can't find anything about it.  I am using the admin panel plugin so when I create a post/item so there is the Frontmatter, actual content/post, and images uploaded (with only insert and delete options).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but I thought it could be nice to have more Q/A about Grav on stackoverflow.

> 1 - How can I add a class to this image when it is output? I want to
>   add an img-responsive class, but see no way to do this.

You need to pass the class as the third parameter of `.html()` like this:

```
{{ header_image_media.cropZoom(header_image_width, header_image_height).html('TITLE', 'ALT', 'CLASS') }}
```

> 2 - What if I don't want a header image at all for the post, but the
>   post will have images in it? Okay, so I remove the {% set
>   header_image_media = page.media.images|first %} part, but with that
>   question is how to I define what image to use as
>   page.media.images[header_image_file] then if I want to use one?

I wouldn't do it this way. I would add a variable for each article `page.header.has header` and then, I would adjust the twig template accordingly.

> 3 - How can I get the full url of this header image for outputting on
>   the page? I am not talking about the full tag, just the string of its
>   full url?

You can use the filter `|absolute`

```
{{ header_image_media.cropZoom(header_image_width, header_image_height).html('TITLE', 'ALT', 'CLASS')|absolute }}
```